# Android GridView Odd item placement

Tags: android, gridview

I have a Gridview with odd number of items with two columns. The items are placed as:

```
Item 1   -  Item 2

Item 3   -  Item 4

Item 5   -  Item 6

Item 7
```

i want the last Item 7 should be in center like this:

```
Item 1   -  Item 2

Item 3   -  Item 4

Item 5   -  Item 6

      Item 7
```

please help me , how to do this through Java code?

Comment: You can't achieve this with a simple GridView.  Have a look at `TableLayout` instead.

Comment: can you help me for the sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get this with default gridView.

There is work around you can use:

1. Try three column and make middle one invisible

   OR
2. Add a separate view below of the grid view.

   OR
3. Create your own gridview implementation

I think these work for you.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218553/gridview-with-last-item-centered