# GridView with last item centered

Tags: android, gridview

I'm doing a GridView (**not dynamic**), that contains 13 values and I want to put it on two columns and it looks like :

[image: one]

And this is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCard"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_27sdp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivCard"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivCard" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCard"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I used `Span` why isn't putting it on the middle?

```
GridLayoutManager recycleLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recycleLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    // grid items to take 1 column
                    if (mList.size() % 2 == 0) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return (position == mList.size()-1) ? 2 : 1;
                    }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've recently implemented something similar. I adapt code a little bit and share with you.

Comment: Thanks.... It's freaking me out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-grid/tree/onlygrid) it is a sample project implementing exactly your scenario.

Basically you have to wrap your cards with a layout having width to be defined programmatically in `onCreateViewHolder` method of the adapter.

In a 2 columns grid, width will be half of parent.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @thetonrifles can you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944939/bluetooth-clossing-sockets-when-using-voice-recognition)? please

Comment: @AndroidWannabe ok, I'll check asap

Comment: @thetonrifles Thanks mate... I think it can be done doing something like global or a global class to connect to bluetooth or something... but the problem is when the activity enters on onPause :(...

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem : I have a GridLayout with two columns and an odd number of elements. The last element must be centered.

I solved it using a custom `SpanSizeLookup` and putting some margins on the last element :

In the RecyclerView / Activity :

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup()
{
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int
    {
        return if (position == 0 || isLastRowAndShouldBeCentered(position)) 2 else 1
    }
}

myRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

And in the Adapter :

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder
{
    // Save the width of the container
    this.containerWidth = parent.measuredWidth

    // Create your ViewHolder here
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
{
    ...

    /**
     * This margin will be exactly 1/4 of the container width.
     * This way, the element will be displayed as follows :
     * [ BLANK 1/4 SPACE ] [ ELEMENT 1/2 WIDTH ] [ BLANK 1/4 SPACE ]
     */
    if (isLastRowAndShouldBeCentered(position))
    {
        val params = viewHolder.view.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
        val marginSize = this.containerWidth / 4 // Re-use the container width here
        params.leftMargin = marginSize
        params.rightMargin = marginSize
        viewHolder.view.layoutParams = params
    }
}
```

Obviously, `isLastRowAndShouldBeCentered` is yours to implement (returns a Boolean indicating whether we are on the last element and we have an odd number of elements)

Hope it can help someone !