# Creating a gridview with different column numbers

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I want to create a gridview like the one on the Medium app that has different column numbers depending on the length of the text.

Using the standard `GridLayoutManager` paired with a `RecyclerView` doesn't seem to be of much help.

Is there a better way to achieve the same effect; while still using a `RecyclerView` if possible.

[image: Medium category selection]

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible. The trick is that here rows of `RecyclerView` is horizontally centered and buttons are dynamically added. You do not to care about positions of each button Since their widths are set to `wrap_content`, and row is horizontally centered, it will automatically render this result. What is up to you is, you have to decide whether to put 2,3 or 4 items in a row. You can define a character limit, maybe considering the paddings of buttons, then you can create your datasource to send to the `RecyclerView`. This is the general concept I can give you without seeing the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try these urls. It may help you

[GridView with last item centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218553/gridview-with-last-item-centered)

https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-grid/tree/onlygrid

Answer (score 0):

this is solution which worked for me with my project and I think it will work for you as well. Let me know if it helped

The layout xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/articles"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/articles2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/articles3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```